# No more username available in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-account

Gmail has a serious problem about the possibility of creating new email addresses.

I was not able to create a name.surname account for the last three people I helped in the creation of an email address.

I think that the problems are two:

1. Gmail does not distinguish between name.surname and namesurname
2. many users have activated the address to access the services Android

Do you know if after a period of non-use usernames return available for Gmail?

Comment: Gmail just ignore the periods. For Gmail `name.surname` and `namesurname` is same.

Comment: Some older email addresses they do distinguish between those with periods and those without

Comment: For myself and my daughter with a fairly common first name, I had to resort to `surname.name@gmail.com`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do you know if after a period of non-use usernames return available
>   for Gmail?

No, they do not.    And some Google services (e.g., Blogger) have promised that this will not happen.

However I do not see that there is a problem:   we are not running out of numbers, so it will always be possible to get   name.surnameNNN accounts, although NNN will become increasingly large.